# Window placement: WinSplit Revolution -like application for Linux (KDE)?

Tags: linux, user-interface, kde-plasma

What is the WinSplit Revolution -like application for Linux (KDE)?
Or maybe there is a functionality in KDE I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a programming related question, I guess.

Anyhow...there seems to be a plugin for compiz-fusion called [grid](http://wiki.compiz-fusion.org/Plugins/Grid), which according to the author is based off of the functionality WinSplit Revolution provides.

Comment: There are also other alternatives like PyTyle and my own QuickTile which, like WinSplit, augment your existing window manager. The Wikipedia page for tiling WMs is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Tiling is typically a function of the window manager.  KWin does not do tiling to my knowledge.  There are numerous tiling managers out there though:

- dwm (C)  (( also, what I prefer due to simplicity ))
- xmonad (haskell)
- awesome (i think lua, based off dwm)
- wmii (C) (( "big brother" to dwm ))

Also, i dont know if this is rumor or not, but I have heard a couple times that Openbox will be getting tiling functionality.  You can run a KDE desktop with openbox as the WM.  This will allow you to have tiling + a desktop-ish environment

But yea.. not really programming related